# How to get the state of a remote job in Livy using Java API

Tags: livy

Is it possible to monitor the state of an already running remote job in Livy with Java API? How can this be done?

I looked over Livy Java API docs. A `JobHandle` would let me pool the state of the app. However, the only way I can see to obtain it is via `LivyClient.submit` while I need to get a handle of the job that was already submitted outside of Java code. I'm afraid that Java API doesn't support it and creating REST calls in Java code is the only option. If anyone has found a way to get information about batch jobs via Livy Java API, please show the code used.